# Does cuda stream has own __constant__ memory copy?

Tags: cuda, stream, gpu-constant-memory

I have a kernel which uses a little `__constant__` memory multiple times and needs to copy different values to `__constant__` memory each time. Recently, I needed to make this kernel multi stream concurrent.

How can I make each stream a copy of that `__constant__` memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make each stream a copy of that `__constant__` memory?

You can't. A `__constant__` variable has context/device level scope. If your code only uses a "little" amount of constant memory, just pass it as a kernel argument. Kernel arguments are stored in a dedicated constant memory bank on all supported architectures.